# Enviar requisições ajax uma a uma

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou enviando um e-mail para uma lista digamos de 100 pessoas, processo este envio via Ajax, o normal é o ajax enviar para uma pagina e no success ou error dele, ele me da o retorno o que ocorreu, até ai blz, já estou fazendo com o Ajax e o PHP, porem eu quero ver se é possível que o retorno seja um a um conforme o while do php for processando o envio, exemplo:

```
Iniciando envio 1....
Email 1 enviado com sucesso
Iniciando envio 2...
Email 2 enviado com sucesso
Iniciando envio 3...
Email 3 enviado com sucesso
Iniciando envio 4...
Erro no envio do Email 4
```

E assim por diante até a lista finalizar, hoje ele me retorna toda aquela mensagem citada acima de uma vez, somente após terminar o while todo do php. Abaixo o código ajax que estou usando

```html
$('#ideMarketing').change(function () {
    var ideMarketing = $('#ideMarketing').val();
    if (ideMarketing == "") {
        $('#verificandoEmail').html("");
        $("#resultVerificandoEmail").html("");
        $('#assunto').val("");
        $('#htmlMensagem').val("")

    } else {
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'pagina_processamento.php',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultVerificandoEmail").html("");
                    $('#verificandoEmail').html("<img src='img/load.gif' id='load'>");
                },
                data: {
                    ideMarketing: ideMarketing
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#resultVerificandoEmail').html(msg);                
                }
            });
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer seu JS percorrer uma lista de e-mails ou contatos e dai chamar sua função.

[Ex1 forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

```
var emails = ["teste1@email.com", "teste2@email.com", "teste2@email.com"];
fruits.forEach(sua_função_de_emails(email));
```

Um segunda abordagem seria deixa seu back-end fazer esse envio, ai na sua linguagem PHP vc pode percorrer sua lista e disparar seus e-mails.

Outra abordagem seria você fazer a integração de seu aplicativo com um serviço de envio de e-mails em massa, tipo SendGrid, Mailgun, MailChimp. Pois esses caras são mais robustos para envio de grandes quantidades de e-mails e com isso você não tem o risco do IP do seu servidor ser taxado spam.

Comment: Então, eu faço o processo de envio pelo php, o ajax é só para não ter que sair da pagina, mais eu mando o retorno para o  success: function (msg) {
                    $('#resultVerificandoEmail').html(msg);                
                } do jquery, o que estou analisando como fazer até no php, mais ainda não consegui pensar em uma lógica para o php e mysql a cada resposta mandar para para o ajax e ai repetir o processo até finalizar.